# Convert json column data into table in sql server 2012

Tags: json, sql-server-2012

I have json stored in table with 3 million rows.
A single row contains json in below format

```
[
   {
      "Transaction":[
         {
            "ProductInfo":[
               {
                  "LINE_NO":"1",
                  "STOCKNO":"890725471381116060"
               },
               {
                  "LINE_NO":"2",
                  "STOCKNO":"890725315884216020"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "Payment":[
         {
            "ENTSRLNO":"1",
            "DOCDT":"08/25/2016"
         }
      ],
      "Invoice":[
         {
            "SALES_TYPE":"Salesinvoice",
            "POS_CODE":"A20",
            "CUSTOMER_ID":"0919732189692",
            "TRXN_TYPE":"2100",
            "DOCNOPREFIX":"CM16",
            "DOCNO":"1478",
            "BILL_DATE":"08/25/2016 03:59:07"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to dump above json in three different table

1. ProductInfo
2. Payment table
3. Invoice

How to perform above task in a optimise way?

Comment: SO is not an "I need this; give me code" service. It is for getting answers to issues with particular parts of programming that you might be experiencing. What code have you already tried? What are you experiencing difficulties with, exactly? Asking us to recommend how to perform a task in an "optimised" way can be considered opinion-based as there are always many ways to skin a cat. Please consider adding the code you've already tried to your question and any issues you're having with that, and you might get some helpful answers :)

Comment: I had tried using  OPENJSON function but it not working in my sql server 2012 because my compatibility_level is 120 and OPENJSON required   compatibility_level 130.And in current scenario i don't  have permission to change database compatibility_level.

Answer (score 1):

Well most efficient way will be to write a procedure and use open json in sql server
check below link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn921879.aspx